# What happened to Elazar ben Aminadav?

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, ark-aron-kodesh

In 1 Shmuel 7:1 we learn that the Aron came to the house of Aminadav and to Elazar his son. Then in 2 Shmuel 6:3 we read that the is transported on a wagon guided by Uzzah and Achiyo the sons of Aminadav. I would like to know if there is any explanation for why Elazar did not participate in the return of the Aron as well.

I understand that the Aron was in the house of Aminadav for many years so it is possible that Elazar died a natural death in that time; I'm looking for any sort of commentary which explains either his fate or his absence from the procession that returned the Ark.

Comment: Which meforshim did you look at?

Comment: @ezra all the ones that are available through sefaria.org connected to both the pesukim referenced in the question